# git difftool dir-diff symlinks issue

Tags: git, difftool

I'm running msysgit 1.8.3 on a larger project under Windows 8.1.

When I issue `git difftool --dir-diff`, any changes I perform to source files on the left pane will persist back to the working dir. This is good and is the desired behavior.

But when I compare to a treeish, for example:

```
git difftool --dir-diff --cached
git difftool --dir-diff stash@{0}
git difftool --dir-diff HEAD^
```

The changes are not saved.

The weird thing is that when I test on a smaller project, I don't have this problem.
It seems like there's an issue when creating symlinks when comparing the large project.
Is there some flag I could use to force creating symlinks?
Alternatively, is there a way to debug why git is not creating the symlinks?

Thanks.

(*) To those who are familiar with it, I'm looking for the behavior of [git-meld](https://github.com/wmanley/git-meld), which used to do this just perfect.

**Edit:**
I found this inconsistency in another different project on a different PC. So now I have two cases like that.
Any help would be appreciated.